# Is there a way to select table_id in a Bigquery Table Wildcard Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a set of day-sharded data where individual entries do not contain the day.  I would like to use table wildcards to select all available data and get back data that is grouped by both the column I am interested in and the day that it was captured.  Something, in other words, like this:

```
SELECT table_id, identifier, Sum(AppAnalytic) as AppAnalyticCount 
    FROM  (TABLE_QUERY(database_main,'table_id CONTAINS "Title_" AND length(table_id) >= 4')) 
    GROUP BY identifier, table_id order by AppAnalyticCount DESC LIMIT 10
```

Of course, this does not actually work because table_id is not visible in the table aggregation resulting from the TABLE_QUERY function.  Is there any way to accomplish this?  Some sort of join on table metadata perhaps?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This functionality is available now in BigQuery through `_TABLE_SUFFIX` pseudocolumn. Full documentation is at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables.
Couple of things to note:

- You will need to use [Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql) to enable table wildcards
- You will have to rename `_TABLE_SUFFIX` into something else in your `SELECT` list, i.e. following example illustrates it

  `` SELECT _TABLE_SUFFIX as table_id, ... FROM `MyDataset.MyTablePrefix_*` ``

Answer (score 12):

Not available today, but something I'd love to have too. The team takes feature requests seriously, so thanks for adding support for this one :).

In the meantime, a workaround is doing a manual union of a SELECT of each table, plus an additional column with the date data.

For example, instead of:

```
SELECT x, #TABLE_ID
FROM table201401, table201402, table201303
```

You could do:

```
SELECT x, month
FROM
  (SELECT x, '201401' AS month FROM table201401),
  (SELECT x, '201402' AS month FROM table201402),
  (SELECT x, '201403' AS month FROM table201403)
```

Comment: Bring and vote for your feature requests here: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/list?q=label:Feature-Request

Comment: Looks like [163](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=163) is the bug we should be voting on to get this feature.