# Get at table ID from wildcard query

Tags: google-bigquery

I'd like to validate whether a range of tables each cover just one day (i.e., that we didn't accidentally put records in the wrong table).

Right now we have tables that look like this:

Table: sometable_20140506

```
pst_date   | pst_hour | ...
2014-05-06 | 10       | ...
2014-05-06 | 10       | ...
2014-05-06 | 11       | ...
2014-05-06 | 11       | ...
2014-05-06 | 12       | ...
```

And I'd like to find any tables where there is more than one unique value for pst_date, e.g. something like:

```
SELECT table_id, COUNT(*) AS num_dates

FROM
    (SELECT
    table_id,
    pst_date
    FROM
    (TABLE_DATE_RANGE(somedataset.sometable_, 
                      TIMESTAMP('2014-05-06'),
                      TIMESTAMP('2014-06-06')))
    GROUP BY table_id, pst_date)
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
GROUP BY table_id
```

You can get at `table_id` in a `TABLE_QUERY`, just wondering if it's possible to get at it in select outside of the `TABLE_QUERY`.

Comment: Similar question (with workaround) at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23158162/is-there-a-way-to-select-table-id-in-a-bigquery-table-wildcard-query

Comment: @DavidMSmith - yeah that is exactly the same, thanks for posting that!